# Desktop Applications on Azure

Tags: azure, cloud, citrix

I know that it is possible to develop and deploy Web & Mobile applications on Azure that can be used over the Internet.

Is it possible to deploy a desktop application on Azure and then run remotely from different locations? the same idea as implemented in Citrix

Comment: you will still need a web platform to expose the desktop application just as citrix. I could help more only if you provide some more details on what exactly are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for [Azure Remote Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/remoteapp/remoteapp-whatis). But be aware that:

> Azure RemoteApp is being discontinued on August 31, 2017.

[Source](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/08/12/application-remoting-and-the-cloud/)

Answer (score 1):

The [Citrix XanApp Essentials Service](https://www.citrix.com/global-partners/microsoft/remote-app.html) is the successor to Azure RemoteApp since it's being deprecated and discontinued in Aug 2017.

> Microsoft announced the next step in its borad parntership with Citrix, helping us develop the next generation of the Azure RemoteApp service. The new Citrix XenApp Essentials Service (previously XenApp "express") builds upon Microsoft's vision of Azure RemoteApp by tapping industry-leading XenApp technology to provide additional management, user experience, and security features.

https://www.citrix.com/global-partners/microsoft/remote-app.html